# Ajax Validate username and password

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need help! I have this code that work very good to validate username in mysql database using Ajax, php and Javascript but when I try to add for validate the password too not work and I have been test all possible ways in my mind!

-- Code in html page to validate username

```
function admin_search(){
    $("#checkuser").click(function(){
        var user_name = $('#admin_user').val();

        if(user_name == ""){
            $("#disp").html("");
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: "checklogin_admin.php",
                    data: "user_name="+ user_name ,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#disp").html(html);
                    }
            })
        return false;
        }
    })
}
```

-- Code in checklogin_admin.php

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name'])) {

            $user_admin = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$user_admin'");

            $row = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if($row == 0) {
                echo "<span style='color:red;'>NOT EXIST</span>";
                    } else
                    {
                        echo "<span style='color:green;' id='exist'>EXIST</span>";
                            }
```

---

Im tying to add for validate the password too with this:

```
function admin_search(){
    $("#checkuser").click(function(){
        var user_name = $('#admin_user').val();
        var user_pass = $('#admin_pass').val();

        if((user_name == "") & (user_pass == "")){
            $("#disp").html("");
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: "checklogin_admin.php",
                    data: "user_name="+ user_name
                          "user_pass="+ user_pass,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#disp").html(html);
                    }
            })
        return false;
        }
    })
}
```

But, nothing works!

Comment: syntax error. `user_name "user_pass="` is invalid in javascript.

Comment: `data: "user_name="+ user_name ,` should be `data: { "user_name" :  user_name },` for starters.

Comment: it doesn't have to be an object. He just has to do proper string concatenation and param building.

Comment: Why is it wrong? what do you think jQuery does with the object? (the object gets turned into a param string before being sent, even as a POST request.)

Comment: @KevinB, Ok, maybe you're right, but I don't like it. It looks too much like GET.

Comment: @KevinB, What about url encoding?  If you build the param string yourself rather than giving jquery an object, does it apply url encoding on the values?  Aha...I knew there was a reason its wrong. I doubt if you give it a query string it parses that and url encodes the parameters, but if you give it an object surely it applies the encoding while building the query string.

Comment: That is definitely a downside, and is why i always use an object. however, using an object has absolutely nothing to do with this question. That's the point i was trying to make. The OP simply forgot to add a `+` to concatenate two strings, and forgot to include a `&` to separate the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data should send a single structure ...

```
data: { "user_name": user_name,
        "user_pass": user_pass },
```

... you could also do something like this ...

```
data: "user_name=" + user_name + "&" + "user_pass=" + user_pass,
```

I personally would recommend the first method ...

In both, be careful of sending the username and password in the clear as part of the URL.

You'll have to adjust the backend PHP to account for the data being sent.

Comment: Adjusted the language and placed in another means ... I was working on these changes as the comments came in.  Thanks!

Comment: It work! thank you  rfornal the line: data: "user_name=" + user_name + "&" + "user_pass=" + user_pass, is working properly and now I can validate both... thank you! I appreciate your help!